# Facebook FQL: uid of friends

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, restfb

I'm using restfb 1.6.5 (the same problem in 1.6.4) and have problems getting the uids of my friends. This works fine (me-query):

```
User fbUserMe = fbClient.fetchObject("me", com.restfb.types.User.class);
logger.debug(fbUserMe.getId());
```

The response body  contains something like: `{"id":"1234","name":"ME" ...}` and `fbUserMe.getId()` returns my uid. With the next code snipped I want to get the uids of my friends (friends-query):

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
sb.append("SELECT uid, first_name, last_name FROM user");
sb.append(" WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())");

List<User> users = fbClient.executeQuery(sb.toString(), User.class);
for(User fbUser : users)
{
  logger.debug(fbUser.getId());
}
```

But this always outputs `null`, although the response body contains this: `[{"uid":5678,"first_name":"Peter" ...} ...]`.

The obvious difference in the response by is `id=1234` for the me-query and `uid=5678` for the friends-query. If I use a custom class `FqlUser` like described in [RestFB](http://restfb.com/#executing-fql-queries) I'm able to get the **uid**. Now I'm uncertain of the **uid**. Do I really get same same **id** (the same my friend would get in a me-Query) or do I get something like the **third_party_id** described in [Facebook: FQL-user](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're getting the uid. The same id your friend would get in a "me query".